# My views won't render to my template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am have been running in circles with this for quite a while now. I'm have an issue with the template not rendering my event venues. I only get the {% else %} statement. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**models:**

```
class Shows(models.Model):
    event_date = models.DateField("Date of event")
    venue = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.venue)
```

**views:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.template import RequestContext

from events.models import Shows


def show_results(request):
    """
    Events - this is the events section.
    """
    events = Shows.objects.all()

    return render_to_response("events/events.html", {
        "events": events,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**template:**

```
<h2>These are events for this month</h2>
{% if events %}
    {% for e in events %}
       <ul>
            <li>{{ e.venue }}</li>
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>There are no events at this time.</p>
{% endif %}
```

**file structure:**

```
/myapp
    /deploy
    /events
        /templates
            /events
                events.html
        admin.py
        models.py
        urls.py
        views.py
    /requirements
    /static
    /templates
    manage.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
```

Comment: Can you put your model class up too, the one that declares Shows.

Comment: Sure thing, sorry about that @fatrock92

Comment: I'm assuming you actually have some entries in your database? What is the output of `Shows.objects.all().count()`?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid yes I do have a few entries in the database. That is why I think this should work.

Comment: Add `{{ events|length }}` above the `{% if events %}` and see what it prints.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I added `{{ events|length }}` and I got `0`

Comment: This means there are no records being returned by your query.

Comment: Right, now I'm looking to see why this is

Answer (score 0):

Your template is trying to iterate `events` as if it were a list of `Shows` instances. However, `get_object_or_404` returns a single object. Right now, you probably have only one record in the DB and thus `get_object_or_404` does not throw an exception.

In order to have `events` store a list of objects rather than a single instance, you could replace `get_object_or_404` with:

```
events = Shows.objects.all()
```

This would return a list of all `Shows` instances.

Comment: If he adds more that one event, he'll get a `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception. Based on the fact that he's iterating the events in the template, I assume he wants a list of all `Shows` instances--not just a single instance. Right now I assume he has just 1 `Shows` record in the DB so it doesn't throw that exception.

Comment: So, you're proposing a solution to a problem that he doesn't have?

Comment: Right now he's getting a single `Shows` instance and trying to iterate it in the for loop--which is not iterable. He needs a list of objects if he's going to iterate it in the template. `get_object_or_404` does not return a list. I'll edit my answer to clarify...

Comment: I do have three `Shows` in the database with a venue and event_date. And I'm thinking it might be what @MicahCarrick mentioned about the `MultipleObjectsReturned`

Comment: You can use my suggested method above, or, `get_list_or_404` if you want the 404 error when no events are available (but you probably don't want that as you have the if/else block in the template).

Comment: Right I don't want the 404 error, but I tried `events = Shows.objects.all()` and that didn't return anything to the template either :/

Comment: Well now I'm stumped. I don't *see* anything else wrong. If you have django-debug-toolbar installed you can view the Context for the template to ensure `events` is in there and can use the `logging` module within your code.

Comment: Thanks @MicahCarrick I'll try the django-debug-toolbar and see if I can see anything.

Comment: Ok, so now I have played with django-debug-toolbar and I see that this isn't event getting to the template, I wonder if it's my file structure which I will post above.